# How to center a large title in navigation bar in the middle?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want an app whose navigation bar looks like this at the end:

[image: picture]

At the moment I'm failing to center the large title of the navigation bar in the middle and next to the back button.

Can someone please help me with that? I don't have any code for this problem yet and I found no solutions on the internet. :/

Comment: You say *" I'm failing to center the large title of the navigation bar "*. Then you say *"I don't have any code for this problem yet"*. Then how have you failed? Show what you have actually tried. Show the actual results.

Comment: I have a navigation bar with customized colors, titles and more and no options to center the large title. No code :)

Answer (score 5):

I know that this is very late but I had the same issue and found couple of ways to achieve it. Please mark the answer as correct if it works. These methods have been tested and works on Xcode 12.4 IOS 13

---

**1. When you want to have a custom offset:**

```
extension UINavigationBar{
    @IBInspectable var LargeTitleOffSet: CGFloat{
        get{
            let pstyle =  largeTitleTextAttributes?[NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle] as? NSParagraphStyle
            return pstyle?.firstLineHeadIndent ?? 0
        }
        set{
            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = newValue
            let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: NSParagraphStyle] = [.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle]
            self.largeTitleTextAttributes = attributes
        }
    }
}
```

And then go to the storyboard and select your **NavigationController's NavigationBar** then from the Attributes Inspector set your offset as shown in the image below. **Note: you might have to clean the build folder and build and run every-time you change the offset for the changes to show up.**
[image]

---

**2. When you want the title to be exactly in the centre and not be able to change it from storyboard**

add the following code to one of your classes:

```
extension UIViewController{
    func centerTitle(){
        for navItem in(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews)! {
             for itemSubView in navItem.subviews {
                 if let largeLabel = itemSubView as? UILabel {
                    largeLabel.center = CGPoint(x: navItem.bounds.width/2, y: navItem.bounds.height/2)
                    return;
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

And call it from **ViewDidAppear (not ViewDidLoad)**:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.centerTitle() //Only this VC's title will be centered
}
```

---

Below is the screenshot of the desired output:
[image]

Comment: This achieves the centering but two problems:
1) You should have that code in viewWillAppear to avoid the user seeing the title start left aligned then jump to center.
2) This change will be temporary if there is a scrollView for as soon as you scroll it will reposition to its original left alignment

Comment: @TomA I totally agree with you. Using viewWillAppear would be better. as per the second thing, my view was not scrollable so I didn't look into that.

Answer (score -2):

If you have a navigation controller you can place this line of code inside of the pushed view controller "viewDidLoad" method and it should auto center the titleView for you:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.title = "Albums"
}
```

Comment: No, it isn't centered :/

Answer (score -2):

You don't have to center anything, you just have to embed your `UIViewController` in a `UINavigationController`.

Follow this:

Go to your AppDelegate and make it look like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let yourViewController = ViewController()
    yourViewController.title = "Albums"
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: yourViewController)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```